# recording chunks with twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

New to twilio. I am trying to make a twilio call to my company's IVR and record the voice chunks. For example, when I dial the IVR, I get:
Hello, welcome to ... Press 1 for ...
Our menu has recently changed, for ... Press 1

I can dial using:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
string accountSid = "xxxxxxxx";
string authToken = "xxxxxxx";
Twilio.TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
var call = CallResource.Create( 9876543210, 1234567890,
                                record: true,
                                recordingChannels: "dual",
                                url: new Uri("http://www.mycompany.com/DialOption"),
                                sendDigits: "wwww1234wwww1234567890")
 }
```

On my webserver, I have:

```
public class DialOptionController : TwilioController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public TwiMLResult Index(VoiceRequest request)
        {  
            var response = new VoiceResponse();           
            response.Pause(19);
            response.Play(digits: "1");           

            response.Pause(19);
            response.Play(digits: "1");

            response.Pause(9);
            response.Play(digits: "1");

            return TwiML(response);
        }
    }
```

How do I get the recording to give me the chunks before I select the option and not the whole recording in one file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot get the call recording in chunks. You only get a link to the entire recording at the end of the call.

The only recording that you can get in chunks is the recording during the `Gather` verb if you select `input=speech` or `input=speech dtmf` instead of the default `input=dtmf`, and provide a value for the `partialResultCallback` parameter. Example:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
var gather = new Gather(input: "speech",
                        action: new Uri("/completed"),
                        partialResultCallback: new Uri("/partial"));
gather.Say("Welcome to Twilio, please tell us why you're calling");
response.Append(gather);
Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
```